# when the particular list in the item is clicked .it loads the data in the particular list

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

when the particular list in the item is clicked .it loads the data in the particular list and send that data to the another activity and set that data in edittext in that activity .how it can be done?pls help me??

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will do your work, post some code and we'll help you where you get stuck.
In general you do this with an `Intent` in the `OnClick` method

**Example:**

```
private static final int REQUEST_EDIT = 1;
...
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyEditActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("module", m);
 intent.putExtra("position", listPosition);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EDIT);
...
```